# Download Xcode 8 from App Store but after install, it's Xcode 7.3.1 install

Tags: xcode8

Download Xcode 8 from App Store but after install, Xcode 7.3.1 install?
[image]

[image]

Comment: Turn it off and on again?

Comment: Yes. several times

Comment: Right Click on `.xcodeProj` - > open with -> select required xcode version.

Comment: I'd just delete Xcode.app and download it again.

Comment: Maybe Xcode 7.3.1 It's installed on a folder distinct than Applications...

Comment: I delete xcode 7.3.1 , after download and install xcode 8

Comment: This is not a programming question. Please ask this elsewhere.

Comment: @RaziPour1993 Any news on this? I have the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

Try upgrading your OS X. Worked for me.